# Когда действительно необходимо использовать void* и ссылку на указатель

Tags: c++, c

Привет всем. Приведите пожалуйста примеры где это реально необходимо использовать указатель на void и в каких случаях нужно создавать псевдоним через ссылку на указатель, желательно кодом, можно минимальными примерами:  Примеры наподобие зачем использовать аргументы функции так: **void foo(Point *& tmp, void * p)**; и можно ли такую конструкцию конвертировать в int?

```
  double a = 10.99;
  void * ptr = &a;
  double * a = static_cast<double*>(p); // норм
  // int * a = static_cast<int*>(p); не скастится, будет случайное значение
```

Comment: Вы решили проэкзаменовать участников форума? Читайте книги по C++ и C.

Comment: Нет, мне действительно это интересно. В книгах подобных примеров где это реально нужно я не увидел.

Comment: В основном использование указателя типа void * нужно в C, чтобы писать обобщенный код, так как там нет ни шаблонов, ни перегрузки функций. Что касается передачи ссылки на указатель, то  это очевидно требуется, когда исходный указатель должен измениться в функции.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @Disastricks Посмотрите определение таких C функций, как qsort и bsearch  относительно использования указателя void *

Comment: @VladD Я проголосовал за закрытие этого вопроса, как слишком общего.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Ну ваш ответ спас бы вопрос :)

Comment: @VladD  А отчего его спасать, если никакая задача не решается, то есть решения не требуется в виде кода, и никто не минусует вопрос?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Ну, это такой дзен-вопрос о том, как правильно, об устаревших концепциях и о разнице между C и C++. Мне такие вопросы нравятся, хоть они и не так уж конкретны.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Например, есть определённая группа программистов, которые пишут на C++ как на чистом C, и у них в коде часто бывает `void*`. Интересно, а есть ли валидный юзкейс для `void*` в C++ кроме случаев прямого управления памятью? Например, двойной `static_cast` через `void*`?

Comment: Оператор-член логирующего класса, указатель на char логируется другой версией как строка, на начало которой он указывает, остальные указатели – как hex значения адресов. Нафига мне этот оператор перегружать для указателя на каждый тип?

Comment: Не случайное. Там будет код дабла или его часть, занимающая старшие адреса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. За примером использования указателя `void *` далеко ходить не надо - посмотрите на стандартную функцию `qsort`, первым параметром которой является как раз указатель `void *`. Посмотрите на стандартную функцию `bsearch`, тоже активно использующую `void *` указатели.
2. Вопрос про ссылки на указатели не ясен. Указатель - это просто тип данных, ничем принципиально не отличающийся от любого другого типа данных. Если вы понимаете, зачем вообще нужны ссылки, то у вас не должно возникать вопросов о том, для чего нужны ссылки на указатели, ибо они ничем из общей массы не выделяются.

Comment: Не вполне понятно, почему в `qsort` _действительно_ нужен `void*` (если отбросить сомнительную цель совместимости с C). Мне кажется, `qsort` вполне мог бы быть шаблонным по типу коллекции

Comment: @VladD: Ну `qsort` - это функция стандартной библиотеки С, реализованная на основе голого run-time полиморфизма. А шаблонная функция в библиотеке С++ уже есть - `std::sort`.

Comment: Тогда это не самый хороший пример того, когда нужно применять `void*`, т. к. мотивация использования `void*` — наличие функции в C, а не что-то ещё.

Comment: @VladD: Не совсем понимаю. Пример альтернативной мотивации: шаблоны в С++, как известно, могут приводить к разбуханию кода (code bloat) из-за того, что фактически один и тот же код может инстанциироваться много раз для разного набора шаблонных аргументов. При большом количестве шаблонных параметров это явление может принять характер комбинаторного взрыва. Одной из техник предотвращения такого разбухания как раз является реализация шаблона, как "тонкой" оболочки над классической С-шной реализацией, построенной на `void *` и run-time параметризации.

Comment: Т.е., к примеру, можно заставить `std::sort` тут же делегировать вызов в некий аналог старого-доброго `qsort` все с теми же `void *` указателями.

Comment: Вот это уже выглядит валидной мотивацией, да. Хотя юзкейс достаточно узкий, например, никто ведь не ожидает, что `std::sort` будет сортировать более ста различных типов в типичной программе. То есть если выкристаллизовать, это runtime-полиморфизм, например, сортировка на случай, если тип станет известен и правда лишь в рантайме, и не протягивается через шаблонные параметры.

Comment: Хе, так в том то и дело что для разработчика библиотеки

Comment: Посмотрите третий параметр ОЧЕНЬ важной функции ioctl. И подумайте - можно ли сделать (Хотя бы только для С++) эту функцию шаблонной :-)